# What is the standard way to use z-score with EEG?

Tags: eeg

I can't understand how to use normalization technique for EEG.

- Is it used for results of FFT or for raw EEG signal?
- Are there different methods with common name "$z$-transform"?
- And what z-score used in [this](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10548-009-0127-0) article?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need a bit of clarity in question. There can be numerous normalization techniques for EEG depending on how they are used. That can be before processing (i.e. raw) or even after processing (for example, with FFT or other transforms).

Z-transform is ONE method. Period. There is nothing else called z-transform. You can have a look on Wikipedia entry of z-transform [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-transform).

Z-score, as used in your article, is a statistical measure, also called the standard score. More info [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_score), again.

To sum up, z-transform and z-score are NOT linked.